# Recovering COnfidence after bike fall

Tags: mountain-bike, touring-bikes, accidents

It's been 3 months since my bike accident, I've had at least 10 critical accidents. Sometimes I don't even know how I am alive. Recently, I had a bike crash when going down the hill which broke of 2 of my 2 front adult tooth. When I fell, my face scraped against the rough terrain, i was unconscious after accident, I had to undergo major surgery on the bottom half my face, My lips had a hole straight through it (enough for a thick pen to be put).

My face has recovered but every time I walk down the hill (everyday), I think of everything that happened that day. The worst thing is the amount of blood from my face on the floor hitting my memory again and again . It shakes me out.

My parents are telling me not to ride again ( I'm 19) but whats the fun in that. I'm trying to build the confidence but its sooo hard.  Also bike became "un- ridable"

Any tips? What bike next? had mountain bikes before, thinking of road bike but doesnt seem like a great idea.

Comment: 10 critical accidents?! Dude, you're not doing it right.

Comment: Whatever you do next, Wear a helmet!

Answer (score 5):

I am not a doctor, but its sound like you might be suffering Post Traumatic Stress, and should seek professional help to rule it out or get treatment.

You should be concerned about the 10 critical accidents (I read critical that as hospital/doctors visits and time off school/work, not a mere "off" ). You are likely riding beyond you limits, and need to learn to ride safer - (rein in the testosterone). Accidents happen, but 10 before the age of 20 is to high.  Its a numbers game, and with that many, one day you will not ride another day.

Have you ever had, and are still getting coaching? This would be my first step. You need to learn why you are pranging and getting hurt, and stop the "getting hurt" bit. Prangs are a part of pushing things when MTBing, getting hurt regularly is not.

In the end, if you cannot rein it in, switching codes (I presume you are down-hilling/freestyling with those stats) to XC, Cyclocross or Road may be wise.

And do listen to you parents. They don't want you to stop riding, they want you to stop getting hurt. They dread having to arrange a funeral or  remodel the house to suit a paraplegic.

Comment: Personally, I am a thrill seeker. Speed has always been my strength and some cases my weakness. When I get angry or upset I rely on speed to calm me down. It gives me the "kick" to keep on going. When I said critical: getting hit by buses, trucks,cars, breaking bones. etc When I read your  second paragraphy I thought we only live once, so what would be life if we do not exceed our limits. I've never had coaching. I learned to ride from the age of 5. Right now, all I'm doing gym,gym, gym. trying to get bulkier, trying to forget the past but its hard to let go. Your last comment touched me...

Comment: @Delvin Yes, we do only live once, and we're dead for a long time :-) So making it last seems like a good idea. There are many other pleasures in life than adrenaline.

Answer (score 2):

I also like speed and racing, but after some close calls (nowhere close to yours) I decided to push my limits going UPHILL, go faster in that 17% climb where 10 mph is the speed of light. And outside of bicycles, there are infinite challenges, running a mile under 5 minutes, learning to swim butterfly, or in strength training, going for the gimnastic bodyweight type, planches, handstand, rings and iron cross, you name it...